# Palm tree disease

Tags: diseases, leaves

[image][image]

Can someone tell me what disease might have this palm tree? It has been losing leaves progressively. And is there any treatment? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fungi on palm leaves is usually due to a poor location for the tree, where the roots cannot get sufficient moisture or air. Waterlogging is a common cause; examine the base of the tree carefully and if you see fungi fruiting heads then consider if the tree is sitting in water for much of the time. If you are watering, then stop and see if the situation improves.

If indeed it is a water issue, consider replacing the palm with a banana tree. Bananas are often planted in limestone "banana holes" where they prefer the moist conditions that the palm will hate.